# Using \TextField Inside a pspicture Environment

Tags: hyperref, luatex, pstricks, textfield

Here follows a MWE showing a problem of mine.

**Code**

```
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\psset{dimen = m}

\def\skala{0.7}
\def\vandret(#1,#2)#3{%
  \multido
    {\i = #1+1}
    {#3}
    {\psframe
      (\fpeval{\skala*(\i-1)},\fpeval{\skala*(#2-1)})%
      (\fpeval{\skala*\i},\fpeval{\skala*#2})}}
%\def\lodret(#1,#2)#3{%
%  \multido
%    {\i = #2+-1}
%    {#3}
%    {\psframe
%       (\fpeval{\skala*(#1-1)},\fpeval{\skala*(\i-1)})%
%       (\fpeval{\skala*#1},\fpeval{\skala*\i})}}

\def\DefaultHeightofText{\skala cm}
\def\DefaultWidthofText{\skala cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(\fpeval{\skala*17},\fpeval{\skala*15})
    \vandret(1,9){8}
    \rput(1,9){\TextField{}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

**Question**

I would like to use the `\TextField` macro from the [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) in order to be able to fill out the crossword interactively. How do I achieve that?

The code above just puts the text field at the bottom left corner of the `pspicture`.

I compile using `lualatex`, in case that is of any importance.

P.S. Feel free to improve my messy code.

**Update**

[image: updated output]

As can be seen in the screenshot, the boxes to the left (where there are no interactive text fields) overlap perfectly, whereas the boxes to the right (where there are interactive text fields) doesn't overlap perfectly.

Here is the entire code of my document:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  danish
]{article}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%            %%
%%   Pakker   %%
%%            %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Skrifttype for tekst.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  NFSSFamily     = tgp,
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Ligatures      = {
    TeX,
    CommonOff
  }
]{texgyrepagella}

% Skrifttype for matematik.
\usepackage[
  math-style = TeX
]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\setmathfont[
  version  = bold,
  FakeBold = 4
]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

% Fiks for størrelsen af cifre i matematik.
\DeclareSymbolFont{textdigits}{TU}{tgp}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{textdigits}{bold}{TU}{tgp}{b}{n}
\Umathcode`0="7 \symtextdigits `0
\Umathcode`1="7 \symtextdigits `1
\Umathcode`2="7 \symtextdigits `2
\Umathcode`3="7 \symtextdigits `3
\Umathcode`4="7 \symtextdigits `4
\Umathcode`5="7 \symtextdigits `5
\Umathcode`6="7 \symtextdigits `6
\Umathcode`7="7 \symtextdigits `7
\Umathcode`8="7 \symtextdigits `8
\Umathcode`9="7 \symtextdigits `9

% Sprog.
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish}

% Flere kolonner i dokumentet.
\usepackage{multicol}

% Specificerer marginer og lignende for dokumentet.
\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}

% Muliggører eget design af sidehoved og -fod.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Antal sider.
\usepackage[
  lastpage
]{zref}

% Baggrundsmateriale.
\usepackage[
  firstpage = true
]{background}

% Placering af floats.
\usepackage{float}

% Forløkker.
\usepackage{multido}

% Intern vektorgrafik.
\usepackage{pstricks}

% Interaktive krydsreferencer med mere.
\usepackage{hyperref}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%             %%
%%   Makroer   %%
%%             %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Afgør, om dokumentet skal udskrives eller læses på en computerskærm.
\newif\ifprint
%\printfalse % Skærmlæsning.
\printtrue  % Papirlæsning.

% Opsætning af pakker.
% ``pstricks''
\psset{
  dimen = m
}
% ``hyperref''
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{
  \ifprint
    % Papirlæsning.
    \hypersetup{
      pdftitle = {Kryds og tværs om vands tilstandsformer},
      pdfauthor = {Mads Sørensen},
      pdfsubject = {Fysik/kemi},
      pdfstartview = FitH,
      bookmarksopen = true,
      bookmarksopenlevel = 1,
      hidelinks
    }
  \else
    % Skærmlæsning.
    \hypersetup{
      pdftitle = {Kryds og tværs om vands tilstandsformer},
      pdfauthor = {Mads Sørensen},
      pdfsubject = {Fysik/kemi},
      pdfstartview = FitH,
      bookmarksopen = true,
      bookmarksopenlevel = 1,
      colorlinks = true,
      citecolor = blue,
      linkcolor = red,
      urlcolor = teal
    }
  \fi
}{}
\makeatother

% Baggrundsmateriale.
\backgroundsetup{
  contents = Navn: \underline{\hspace{10em}},
  scale = 1,
  color = black,
  angle = 0,
  opacity = 1,
  position = current page.north west,
  vshift = -2cm,
  hshift = 5.13cm
}

% Automatisk placering af floats.
\makeatletter
  \providecommand*\floatlocation[2]{\@namedef{fps@#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\floatlocation{figure}{H}

% Letter notationen.
\def\skala{0.93}
\def\DefaultHeightofText{\skala cm}
\def\DefaultWidthofText{\skala cm}

\def\vandret(#1,#2)#3{%
  \multido
    {\i = #1+1}
    {#3}
    {\psframe
      (\fpeval{\skala*(\i-1)},\fpeval{\skala*(#2-1)})%
      (\fpeval{\skala*\i},\fpeval{\skala*#2})}}
\def\lodret(#1,#2)#3{%
  \multido
    {\i = #2+-1}
    {#3}
    {\psframe
       (\fpeval{\skala*(#1-1)},\fpeval{\skala*(\i-1)})%
       (\fpeval{\skala*#1},\fpeval{\skala*\i})}}
\def\bogstav(#1,#2)#3{%
  \rput(\fpeval{\skala*(#1-0.5)},\fpeval{\skala*(#2-0.5)})
       {\MakeUppercase{#3}}}
\newcommand*\ord[1]{%
  \raisebox{0.4ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle\bullet$}\enskip\text{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\def\skrivefelt(#1,#2)#3{%
  \put(\fpeval{\skala*(#1-1)},\fpeval{\skala*(#2-1)})
      {\TextField[
         borderwidth = \pslinewidth,
         bordercolor = 0 0 0,
         align = 1,
         name = #3
       ]{}}}

% Opsætning af sidehoved og -fod.
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop*{numpage}{\the\value{page}}
\zref@addprop{main}{numpage}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \ifnum \zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{numpage}{0} > 1
    \thepage
  \fi
    %
}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                      %%
%%   Selve dokumentet   %%
%%                      %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \bfseries
  \huge
  Vands tilstandsformer
\end{center}
\vspace{8ex}

\noindent
Indsæt ordene i skemaet nedenfor.

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  &\ord{is}       &\qquad\quad &\ord{kogepunkt}  \\
  &\ord{gas}      &            &\ord{smeltning}  \\
  &\ord{fast}     &            &\ord{størkning}  \\
  &\ord{vand}     &            &\ord{fortætning} \\
  &\ord{afkøling} &            &\ord{opvarmning} \\
  &\ord{flydende} &            &\ord{smeltepunkt}\\
  &\ord{vanddamp} &            &
\end{alignat*}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(\fpeval{\skala*17},\fpeval{\skala*15})
%    \vandret(7,15){11}
    \multido
      {\iA = 7+1,
       \iB = 1+1}
      {11}
      {\skrivefelt(\iA,15){vA\iB}}
%    \vandret(9,13){8}
    \multido
      {\iA = 9+1,
       \iB = 1+1}
      {8}
      {\skrivefelt(\iA,13){vB\iB}}
%    \vandret(1,9){8}
    \multido
      {\iA = 1+1,
       \iB = 1+1}
      {8}
      {\skrivefelt(\iA,9){vC\iB}}
    
    \vandret(5,6){9}
    \vandret(2,3){9}
    \vandret(8,1){3}
    \lodret(1,9){4}
    \lodret(2,5){4}
    \lodret(3,15){10}
    \lodret(5,7){2}
    \lodret(8,10){10}
    \lodret(10,13){11}
    \lodret(12,11){8}
    \lodret(16,15){9}
%    \bogstav(10,13){f}
%    \bogstav(10,12){o}
%    \bogstav(10,11){r}
%    \bogstav(10,10){d}
%    \bogstav(10,9){a}
%    \bogstav(10,8){m}
%    \bogstav(10,7){p}
%    \bogstav(10,6){n}
%    \bogstav(10,5){i}
%    \bogstav(10,4){n}
%    \bogstav(10,3){g}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry no, make your code minimal.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've tried to remove some more code not directly related to the problem described.

Comment: a textfield must have a (unique) name: \TextField[name=blub]{}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hmm! If I try `\rput(1,9){\TextField[name = blub]{}}` the text field is still placed at the bottom left corner of the picture. Can I make you give an answer with a fully working example, then I can accept it (obviously) and will do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\put(1,9){\TextField[name=blub]{}}
```

instead of `\rput`

[image]

Or for more than one textfield:

```
\put(1,9){\multido{\iA=1+1}{6}{\TextField[name=blub\iA,align=1]{}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That works but when I type a letter in a box, it's not visible after I remove the cursor. Is it something to do with it being in the background of the page?

Comment: no problem here. I used the default pdf viewer from macOS

Comment: It is indeed a PDF viewer problem, I can see! Is it possible to centre the typed text in each box?

Comment: `\TextField[name=blub,align=1]{}`.  it is _number_ 1, not l

Comment: I'm trying to make the `\TextField`s next to each other overlap perfectly but it looks a bit like if I set `dimen = i` in PSTricks when drawing boxes next to each other. Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: example!  Don't understand your problem ...

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: `\put(1,9){\multido{\iA=1+1}{6}{\TextField[name=blub,align=1]{}}}`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this solves my problem. `:-(` Can I make you update your answer with a complete example?

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: I can see that there isn't a problem for you, but at my end there is. ... I'll accept your answer none the less.